# Column label of max in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to extract maximum value in row and contributing column label from pandas dataframe. For example,

```
       A B C D
index 
x     0 1 2 3
y     3 2 1 0
```

I expect the following output,

```
      A  B  C  D  Maxv Con
index 
x     0  1  2  3  3  D   
y     3  2  1  0  3  A
```

I tried the following,

```
df['Maxv'] = df.apply(max,axis=1)
df['Con'] = df.idxmax(axis='rows')
```

It returned only the max column and 'NaN' for Con column. What is the error here?

Thanks in Advance.

AP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need `axis='columns'` or `axis=1` in [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df['Con'] = df.idxmax(axis='columns')
print (df)
       A  B  C  D  Maxv Con
index                      
x      0  1  2  3     3   D
y      3  2  1  0     3   A
```

Or:

```
df['Con'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
print (df)
       A  B  C  D  Maxv Con
index                      
x      0  1  2  3     3   D
y      3  2  1  0     3   A
```

You get `NaN`s, because data are not align to `index`:

```
print (df.idxmax(axis='rows'))
A    y
B    y
C    x
D    x
dtype: object
```